# Can you delete a partition and the filesystem on it with parted?

Tags: linux, partition, parted

I created a partition with `parted` and then removed it using `parted /dev/<partition> rm partition number`. After that I executed `partprobe`,`udevadm settle` and `systmelctl daemon-reload`. Then I used `lsblk` and the partition was not showing. Then when I tried to create another partition with same size using `parted` I was able to but when I tried to use `mkfs.xfs` on that partition, it said the data already exists. It said use the `-f` option overwrite the data with new file system.

My question is that can you remove the partition and filesystem at the same time using parted? If not, then using `fdisk` or `gdisk` is better?
Also, what's the difference between `partprobe`,`udevadm settle` and `systmelctl daemon-reload`? Do you use it after creating a partition with parted or after writing a file system on it or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parted` doesn't have an option for removing the filesystem, you can use `wipefs` before running the command. `fdisk` will ask you to remove existing filesystems when creating a partition and you can also use `--wipe-partitions always` to make this automatic.

`partprobe` tells kernel to re-read the partition table on the device. You don't need to run this manually, both `parted` and `fdisk` do this after making partition table changes (they use the `BLKRRPART`/`BLKPG` ioctls to do that).

`udevadm settle` just waits until [UDev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) finishes with current queue of events. Again, no need to run this manually, you are not using any tool that relies on UDev (like [UDisks](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/udisks/)) and again, it's up to the tools/users of UDev to deal with this.

`systmelctl daemon-reload` is used to reload systemd manager configuration. This has nothing to do with partitioning.